# Google BigQuery: Are we charged when resources exceed during query execution?

Tags: google-bigquery

I wonder if we are charged when the query failed and we get the error message:
"Error: Resources exceeded during query execution."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You're only charged for successful queries.